# How do I run maven-jdeps-plugin on a pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, java-9, jdeps

In my `pom.xml` I've added the maven-jdeps-plugin:

```
<project ...>
  <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
  <artifactId>optaplanner-examples</artifactId>
  <!-- packaging is the default, so "jar" -->
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jdeps-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <goals>
          <goal>jdkinternals</goal>
          <goal>test-jdkinternals</goal>
        </goals>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

but when I run this with JDK 8 and maven 3.3.3, **the jdeps plugin does not do any checks**:

```
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests | grep plugin
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-plugin-versions) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (ban-uberjars) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (validate) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (no-managed-deps) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create (get-scm-revision) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-source (default) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:parse-version (default) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-direct-dependencies) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:test-jar (test-jar) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:test-jar-no-fork (attach-test-sources) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:integration-test (default) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:verify (default) @ optaplanner-examples ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ optaplanner-examples ---
```

Extra info:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

Comment: is your snippet correct? goals cannot be there in the xml structure of a maven plugin, they should be part of an executions/execution

Comment: I could swear they could be nested directly in maven... stupid mistake. Too bad Maven doesn't fail fast on it, but just ignores it.

Comment: that's probably why the plugin is not executed, you need an execution to specify goals as part of the build

Comment: A look ino the [plugin home page is also helpful](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/usage.html)..

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was tagged with Java-9. The [maven jdeps plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/) version `3.1.0` was officially [released recently](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/09/02/apache-maven-jdeps-plugin-3-dot-1-0-released/) and is claimed to be [compatible with jdk9](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) as well.

The official [usage page of the plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/usage.html) as pointed out in comments by @khmarbaise as well, states the implementation as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jdeps-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>jdkinternals</goal> <!-- verify main classes -->
          <goal>test-jdkinternals</goal> <!-- verify test classes -->
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

wherein

> If there is any usage detected of an internal API, the build will stop
>   and fail.

which can be configured using a flag [`failOnWarning`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/jdkinternals-mojo.html#failOnWarning) which has a default value set as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As Di Matteo suggested in the comments, this config fixes it:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jdeps-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>jdkinternals</goal>
          <goal>test-jdkinternals</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

The usage of `<goals>` directly under `<plugin>` is [deprecated, doesn't work](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_plugin) but doesn't fail fast...